# 'I have a certain medical condition, against/for which I take pills'

Tags: word-choice

Which is better between 'against' and 'for' in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe '**for**' to be the correct usage. While it does make some sort of sense to view the medication as working against the disease/condition, I've never heard it that way. I always hear:

> I take medications for my condition.